# piping strace to grep

Tags: io-redirection, strace

I'm trying to run `strace` trough `ccze`, and the pipe doesn't work as expected.

The command-line I'm running to test is `sudo strace -p $(pgrep apache2)  | grep open`, and all lines are output, ignoring grep.

Is there something special about `strace` that causes this behavior?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`strace` prints its traces on standard error, not on standard output. That's because it's common to want to redirect the standard output of the program, but usually not a problem that strace's stderr and the program's stderr are mixed.

So you should redirect `strace`'s stderr to stdout to be able to pipe it:

```
sudo strace -p $(pgrep apache2) 2>&1 | grep open
```

except that what you're really looking for is

```
sudo strace -p $(pgrep apache2) -e open
```

Comment: it works!! thank you! - I wasn't actually trying to look only at `open` calls, I just put that as an example, what I'm really trying to do is color highlighting

Comment: I am getting `strace: Invalid process id: '-e'` with the last command.

I am on version 4.8. 2010-03-30.

Comment: Ahh, I actually have httpd (RHEL).

Comment: @ElijahLynn Replace `apache2` by the name of the process you're interested in. Check that `pgrep` prints a single PID, otherwise pick one and run e.g. `sudo strace -p 1234 -e open`

Comment: @Andrei, what about using `vim` color syntax highlighting? `strace $CMD 2>&1 > /dev/null | vim -c ':set syntax=strace' -`.