# Write strace output to a file

Tags: files, pipe, strace

I'm trying to write the output of `strace ls` to a file. I know that I need to use `>` in order to forward output of a command to a file, but it doesn't work. It creates a file but the command prints the output of `strace ls` to stdout but writes the file name into the file.

```
$ strace ls > ls_sys.txt
...
strace output
...
$ cat ls_sys.txt
ls_sys.txt
```

Comment: Related: [piping strace to grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48223/piping-strace-to-grep) however it will likely be simpler to use the strace `-o` option rather than shell redirection

Comment: Have you tried `strace -o ls_sys.txt ls`?

Comment: I filed an issue to strace about its help here: https://github.com/strace/strace/issues/284

Answer (score 30):

By default strace outputs to stderr. By simply typing `man strace`, you will have the full documentation of `strace`. In the manual page, it states that the `-o` option can be used to output it to a file instead of stderr. You can type `man [insert command here]` for the vast majority of programs, and have all the documentation you will need to effectively use them.

Comment: `By default strace outputs to stderr, which is not accessible via grep or file redirection`. Good to know! And I looked at the manual page of `strace` but I didn't see the `-o` option, my fault. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, I actually just figured out this strace option myself yesterday. When you are in a man page, you can press `/` and it will bring a dialog that you can search. In my case, I simply searched for output and found the part of the man page I was looking for.

Comment: What on Earth makes you think that you cannot redirect standard error or arrange for it to be sent through a pipe to `grep`?

Comment: stderr can be redirected, using `2>`. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440).

Comment: @JdeBP lack of knowledge

Comment: A bash-ism I guess is `command |& command` it merges and pipes both _stdout_ and _stderr_ to the next command.

Answer (score -2):

For those looking for a command to run:

`strace ./elf_file 2>strace_output.txt`

Comment: Note that it redirects both the `strace` tracing and the `./elf_file` errors to `strace_output.txt`. For that reason, it's better  to use `strace -o strace_output.txt ./elf_file` or `strace -o strace_output.txt ./elf_file 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt` if you want traces, stdout and stderr in different files.